# Extracting data in gml tag using Terminal on Mac

Tags: xml, bash, terminal

how to extract a value like 32722 from the following gml tag (using any terminal command on Mac)

```
<gml:srsID>
  <gml:name codeSpace="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::">32722</gml:name>
</gml:srsID>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk -F"[><]" '/<gml:name/{print $3}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Just one little thing, it returned several lines, I needed only the first one. Hence, I saved the output to a temp.txt file then head -n 1 temp.txt

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, so if very first value only you need and nothing else, then you could add ;exit after print $3 and let me know if this helps.

Comment: yes, this is perfect. I don't need the intermediate step now. Thanks a lot